# Is an upsert possible with Kafka Connect to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, upsert, apache-kafka-connect

I'm receiving events which end up in Kafka. From these events I fetch the id using a Kafka Streams application and posting it back to Kafka as a pair of (id, 1) in another topic. Then I would like to see if the id exists already in ElasticSearch, and if so update its counter, otherwise create a new record in ElasticSearch with the id from Kafka and counter set to 1, i.e. an upsert of the record (id, 1) to ES.

I was hoping to use Kafka Connect to ElasticSearch for this, but it seems to be not that straightforward if possible at all. I can see that adding records to ES works, but merging with existing records seems is something I haven't found out about yet. Is this possible already, and if so, how, and if not, is it planned to be possible in a nearby release?

Answer (score 3):

I forked the [datamountaineer ES sink connector](http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/elastic.html) to allow Upsert. With it you can specify a PK and run an update with docAsUpsert into ES. You can grab the project and compile the Jar from [my github fork](https://github.com/tamarr/stream-reactor).

Comment: Note the [updated answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561257/6952495). You simply need to add this to the Kafka ES Connector config: `write.method=upsert`

Comment: It seems like the lenses Elastic Sink Connector has this functionality now as well https://docs.lenses.io/4.2/integrations/connectors/stream-reactor/sinks/elasticsinkconnector/

Comment: @RyanQuey this Q&A was almost 5 years ago :D glad to hear there are formal solutions now

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I didn't mean to imply that the answers given here or your solution are wrong or unhelpful - hopefully it didn't come across that way. I just wanted to redirect others who are looking for an answer to this and come across this post (like myself) to more up to date information. I upvoted both question and answer fwiw :)