# Avoid overwriting fields when for null values in Confluent Elasticsearch Connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have an enrichment pipeline that updates a dynamic number of fields, writes to Kafka, and then sends to Elasticsearch. We are using the [Confluent Elasticsearch Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/configuration_options.html).

E.g., if first record sent to the ES Connector is like:

```
{id: 1, name: "Bob", age: null}
```

And enriched record is something like:

```
{id: 1, name: null, age: 34}
```

I want to have a resulting record in Elasticsearch to be:

```
{id: 1, name: "Bob", age: 34}
```

The reason that the enriched record has to have a null value (i.e., in our example above `name: null`) instead of just not setting the key at all is that it's coming from Avro data and our schema lists several fields as optional. Since the enrichment pipeline is updating a dynamic number of fields, this seems to be the most straightforward solution (i.e., might be updating the `name` field in one record, but the `age` field in another). Since optional Avro fields are defaulting to `null`, this is where our null values are coming from.

I tried the `write.method=upsert` setting [as shown in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554122/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-when-using-write-method-as-upsert-is-it-possible/61561257#61561257), but this seems to still overwrite all fields that have `null` as the value of the enriched record. I.e. per the example above, the resulting record in ES looks like `{id: 1, name: null, age: 34}`. The post linked above seems to have solved this by having multiple Avro schemas for a single record type, which doesn't work for us since it adds too much complexity.

I noticed that ES Connector also has a setting for `behavior.on.null.values` but my understanding is that this is for when entire records are `null`, not individual fields.

Is there a setting in Confluent ES Sink Connector that is something like [`nullToUnset` in the Datastax C* Connector](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/configuration_reference/kafkaDseTable.html#kafkaCassandraTable__nullToUnset)?

If not, is there a good way to implement this?

Comment: Since it is null, what happens if you exclude the name field from the record? Avro doesn't care if the field is actually there, but does the Connector?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I might be confused about how Avro works, but my understanding is if I exclude the name field, it will be sent as the default, which is `null`. Accordingly, I don't know if it's possible to actually exclude the name field without it still sending null. Do you know of a way around this?

Comment: The connect converter should just take the fields that are available as part of the record forward to the sink. I haven't debugged enough of the Avro converter to know if it fully deserializes the record first to apply any defaults

Comment: @OneCricketeer Everything I've tried at least seems to indicate that it is applying defaults. It would be great if there's a way around that though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant line of code is here:
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/elasticsearch/DataConverter.java#L170

This basically means that the source document is sent as is to the index - no modifications.

Your best option is probably to add an SMT that reads the source document and removes any fields with null values.

Comment: I was thinking about this one - I had trouble finding an SMT that actually removes fields. For example, [Mask Fields](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/maskfield.html) seems to only remove the value, which seems like it would leave me in the same place as before. Is there an SMT that actually does this?

Comment: ReplaceField should do what you need, using the 'blacklist' configuration: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/replacefield.html

Comment: In this case, what you actually want is a conditional transformation, based on the value of the field (if value == null then drop field). I don't think there is a built-in transform predicate for field matching, though. It might make more sense to use a custom SMT instead.

Comment: Great thanks, I'll give a custom SMT a try

Comment: Try starting your code from this: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/ReplaceField.java  . Handling the modified schema can be tricky, so follow the code carefully.

Comment: Here's the final solution in case anyone's interested: https://github.com/Anant/kafka-connect-SMT-remove-null-fields