# How to deserialize Avro schema and then abandon schema before write to ES Sink Connector using SMT

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

### Use Case and Description

[My use case is described more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69466943/avoid-overwriting-fields-when-for-null-values-in-confluent-elasticsearch-connect/69477122?noredirect=1#comment122805444_69477122), but the gist of the issue is:

I am making a custom SMT and want to make sure the Elasticsearch sink connector deserializes incoming records properly, but then after that I don't need any sort of schema at all. Each record has a dynamic amount of fields set, so I don't want to have any `makeUpdatedSchema` step ([e.g., this code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0c707b1fccd0b21a3ead765d61f376f338c69bd0/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/ReplaceField.java#L169-L173)) at all. This both keeps code more simple and I would assume improves performance since I don't have to recreate schemas for each record.

### What I tried

I tried doing something like the `applySchemaless` code [as shown here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.0.0/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/InsertField.java#L160) even when the record has a schema by returning something like this, with null for schema:

```
return newRecord(record, null, updatedValue);
```

However, in runtime it errors out, saying I have an incompatible schema.

### Key Question

I might be misunderstanding the role of the schema at this point in the process (is it needed at all once we're in the Elasticsearch sink connector?) or how it works, and if so that would be helpful to know as well. But is there some way to write a custom SMT like this?

Comment: Here's a working solution when keeping the schema. Was never able to figure out a way without the schema (and I'm still not sure why). 

https://github.com/Anant/kafka-connect-SMT-remove-null-fields